# Unrolled Loops of Static Arrays

Tags: static, d, loop-unrolling, static-array, iota

If I call the function

```
/** Check if all Elements, possibly recursively, of $(D x) are zero. */
bool allZero(T)(in T x) @safe pure nothrow {
    import std.range: isIterable;
    static if (isIterable!T) {
        foreach (ref elt; x) {
            if (!elt.allZero) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return x == 0;
    }
}
```

with a static array will D unroll the `foreach` for me automatically in release mode?

If not could

```
/** Static Iota. */
import std.typetuple: TypeTuple;
template siota(size_t from, size_t to) { alias siotaImpl!(to-1, from) siota; }
private template siotaImpl(size_t to, size_t now) {
    static if (now >= to) { alias TypeTuple!(now) siotaImpl; }
    else                  { alias TypeTuple!(now, siotaImpl!(to, now+1)) siotaImpl; }
}
```

be used to achieve unrolling instead of `foreach`?

Further is there a flag to DMD that generates assembly code so that I myself, in the future, can investigate the code generated by DMD?

**Update**: Here's my solution so far.

```
/** Check if all Elements, possibly recursively, of $(D x) are zero. */
bool allZero(T, bool useStatic = true)(in T x) @safe pure nothrow { // TODO: Extend to support struct's and classes's'
    static        if (useStatic && isStaticArray!T) {
        foreach (ix; siota!(0, x.length)) {
            if (!x[ix].allZero) { return false; } // make use of siota?
        }
        return true;
    } else static if (isIterable!T) {
        foreach (ref elt; x) {
            if (!elt.allZero) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return x == 0;
    }
}
```

Does it look ok?

Comment: David Simcha gave an [interesting talk](http://youtu.be/yMNMV9JlkcQ?t=35m24s) that included a section on automated loop unrolling using D's metaprogramming features at DConf 2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> with a static array will D unroll the foreach for me automatically?

No, the language does not guarantee it. Some implementations (compilers) might unroll the loop as an optimization.

> If not could my implementation of static iota (siota) be used to achieve this?

Yes, using foreach over a tuple generates code for every "iteration", effectively unrolling the loop.

> Further is there a flag to DMD that generates assembly code so that I myself, in the future, can investigate the code generated by DMD?

No, DMD cannot emit assembly listings. You can use a disassembler (such as [obj2asm](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/obj2asm.html) or [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml)), or a different compiler instead.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, all D compilers do unroll. Even DMD. But as you say, it is not guaranteed.